How to show that the square root of a matrix is concave?
Let $A$ and $B$ be two symmetric positive semidefinite matrices.
How can we prove that
$$\sqrt{\lambda A + (1 - \lambda) B} \succeq \lambda \sqrt{A} + (1 - \lambda) \sqrt{B}$$
for any $\lambda \in (0, 1)$?
Here, $\sqrt{A}$ represents the square root of $A$. And the notation $A \succeq B$ represents that $A - B$ is positive semidefinite.

A related question

Start with $(\sqrt{A}-\sqrt{B})^2\geq0$. Expanded, this is
$$
\sqrt{A}\sqrt{B}+\sqrt{B}\sqrt{A}\leq A+B.
$$
Then
$$
(\lambda-\lambda^2)(\sqrt{A}\sqrt{B}+\sqrt{B}\sqrt{A})\leq(\lambda-\lambda^2)( A+B).
$$
Since $\lambda-\lambda^2=(1-\lambda)-(1-\lambda)^2$,
$$
(\lambda-\lambda^2)(\sqrt{A}\sqrt{B}+\sqrt{B}\sqrt{A})\leq(\lambda-\lambda^2) A+[(1-\lambda)-(1-\lambda)^2]B,
$$
which we can rewrite as
$$
\lambda^2A+(1-\lambda)^2B+(\lambda-\lambda^2)(\sqrt{A}\sqrt{B}+\sqrt{B}\sqrt{A})\leq\lambda A+(1-\lambda)B.
$$
That is,
$$
(\lambda\sqrt A+(1-\lambda)\sqrt B)^2\leq \lambda A+(1-\lambda)B.
$$
As the square root is operator monotone,
$$
\lambda\sqrt A+(1-\lambda)\sqrt B\leq \sqrt{\lambda A+(1-\lambda)B}.
$$
